# vue push property on an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

I have a component that has to push a property into an array, this is the array:

```
  [
    {
      date: "17/11/2020",
      dateTime: false,
      hour: "00",
      minute: "00",
    },
  ];
```

the component has a button:

```
      <b-button
        class="p-0"
        variant="success"
        @click="addTime(array)"
      >
        + Add more times
      </b-button>
```

I would like every click on the button to add a "time" property like this:

```
       [
         {
           date: "17/11/2020",
           dateTime: false,
           hour: "00",
           minute: "00",
           time: [
             {
               defaultDateStart: "08:00",
               defaultDateEnd: "00:00"
             },
             {
               defaultDateStart: "08:00",
               defaultDateEnd: "00:00"
             },
               //etc....
           ],
         },
       ];
```

It's possible? i tried to use .push() in the click method, but it doesn't work...

Comment: show your code whatever have you tried  so far

Comment: your `time` property is malformed ... it should be an array of objects, not the impossible object of arrays - other than that, you'd want to `this.whateverTheArrayIsCalled[0].time.push(whatYouWantToPush)`

Comment: @FahadSubzwari

i tried this:
      `  methods: {
          addTime(array) {
            const hour = {
              defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
              defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
            };
            array.push(hour);
          },
        },
`

But it does not work

Comment: @Bravo
I tried, it gives me this error
**on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"]**

Comment: perhaps you've mistyped `whateverTheArrayIsCalled`? You haven't shown where that data is (i.e. is it a property of a component data? is it some global? something else?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do make your object like this

```
  let records = [
   {
    date: "17/11/2020",
    dateTime: false,
    hour: "00",
    minute: "00",
    time : []
   },
 ];
```

and in your funciton `addTime` you can do like this

```
addTime(timeObject){
   // timeObject = {defaultDateStart: "08:00",defaultDateEnd: "00:00"} 
   records[0].time.push(timeObject)
}
```

Comment: ok, i wrote this and it works:
      `      methods: {
         addTime(array) {
           array.time = [];
           const hour = {
             defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
             defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
           };
           array.time.push(hour);
         },
       },`
but only on the first click, in subsequent clicks it does not add other "time" objects

Comment: Because you are doing wrong. On every click of `addTime` you are antialiazing a value of `arra.time`  to `[]` so how can you acheive this? That's why i told you that you should already have `time : []` in your each object and then in your `addTime` function you should just do this `const hour = {defaulTimeStart: "08:300", defaultTimeEnd: "00:00:00"}; array.time.push(hour)`

Comment: The problem is that I don't create the initial array but I get it automatically, ready, from a library that I have installed .... do you think it is possible to modify it from the library?

Comment: so you can modify that initial array and use that modified array in your further code